# Image position is not updated

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make a button change its position once clicked. I have read that in order to set my components' positions manually. Thus I declared the default layout manager of my Frame as null. However my button's remains the same although the debugger tell me I am getting new (x, y) each time the button is clicked. Here is my source code :

Class GameUI.java :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import de.tk1.g4.ta1.model.Player;

public class GameUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String header[] = new String[]{"Player", "Score"};
    private JTable table = new JTable();
    private DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    private JPanel sidePanel = new JPanel();
    private ImagePanel bodyPanel = new ImagePanel();


    public GameUI() {
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
        table.setEnabled(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(sidePanel);
        getContentPane().add(bodyPanel);
        sidePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sidePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        sidePanel.add(table);
        sidePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        sidePanel.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 500);
        bodyPanel.setBounds(300, 0, 700, 500);
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(700 + 300, 500));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700 + 300, 500));
        setResizable(false);
        super.paintComponents(getGraphics());
        this.pack();    
    }

    public void addPlayerToList (Player thePlayer) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{thePlayer.getName(), thePlayer.getScore()});
        super.paintComponents(getGraphics());
    }

    public void clearPlayersTable() {
        while(model.getRowCount() > 0)
        {
            model.removeRow(0);
        }
    }

    public void setPokemonLocation (int x, int y) {
        bodyPanel.getBtnPokemon().setLocation(x, y);
        //repaint();
    }

    public JButton getPokButton () {
        return bodyPanel.getBtnPokemon();
    }

    public ImagePanel getBodyPanel() {
        return bodyPanel;
    }

    public void setBodyPanel(ImagePanel bodyPanel) {
        this.bodyPanel = bodyPanel;
    }

    public void setImage(String path) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            Image img = ImageIO.read(fis);
            bodyPanel.getBtnPokemon().setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }   

    public void setPokButton(int x,int y,String path) {     
        bodyPanel.setImage(path);       
        bodyPanel.getBtnPokemon().setLocation(x, y);        
    }

    public void addPokemonListener(ActionListener listenForPokemon) {
        bodyPanel.getBtnPokemon().addActionListener(listenForPokemon);      
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        super.paintComponents(getGraphics());
    }
}
```

Class ImagePanel.java :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton btnPokemon = new JButton("");
    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
        super();
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(700, 450));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 450));
        this.add(btnPokemon);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (g != null && image != null) {
            super.paintComponent(g);            
            g.drawImage(image, btnPokemon.getX(), btnPokemon.getY(), null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        super.paintComponents(getGraphics());
    }

    public void setImage(String path) {
        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            btnPokemon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JButton getBtnPokemon() {
        return btnPokemon;
    }

    public void setBtnPokemon(JButton btnPokemon) {
        this.btnPokemon = btnPokemon;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

Although my controller calls `this.gameUI.revalidate();` and `this.gameUI.repaint();`.

Any hints what I did miss in my source code please.

Comment: `super.paintComponents(getGraphics());`??? This is just so wrong. The whole thing looks a bit crazy. What are you trying to do here? This is not how to change position to be sure.

Comment: I am trying to draw my image at different position where (x, y) I get from the server each time the button btnPokemon is being clicked.

Comment: This is not how Swing graphics is done, not at all. You should never call `paintComponent` or `paintComponents` directly, **ever**. Did you go through the [Swing Graphics tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) before trying all this?

Comment: `getContentPane().setLayout(null);` ... honestly, make appropriate use of layout managers. Never call ANY paint method yourself, this is not how painting is done, instead, when you change the image, simply call `repaint` on the component you want updated

Comment: *"I am trying to make a button change its position once clicked."* ***..why?*** What application feature does that provide to the end user?

Comment: It is a small game. The first player who clicks on the button, gets the point. After that the button change its position to appear in another location. and so on.

Comment: *"The first player who clicks on the button, gets the point."* I don't understand how you expect to manage two mice in a single GUI (unless it's networked & the two users are using separate machines). Having said that, I wouldn't use components for this, but instead custom paint the entire playing area. And a tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.